# Exponential function formula proof

Tags: summation, exponential-function

How does one arrive at $e^4$ from

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{ 4^x}{x!}$$

Comment: The simplest way is to define $e^x$ like this... What is your definition of the exponential? Wait: your summation does not make any sense... It should be $e^x=\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n/n!$.

Comment: What do you mean by definition?

Comment: Are you asking for the definition of the word definition? What is $e^x$ for you?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition. How does one arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: First, please note that the summation does not make sense in your question. This should be the one I wrote down in my first comment. Second, in the link you mention, this series is taken to be the first definition of $e^x$. You don't prove a definition. It is what it is. Now if you define $e^x$ to be the unique solution of the ODE $y'=y$ with $y(0)=1$, then you can prove it must be equal to the power series above.

Comment: Or you can use the limit definition of the exponential function and then prove that it is differentiable infinity of times and then find the coefficients of its Taylor expansion and fact that its Taylor series converges to it.

Comment: @julien Oh, it seems that he changed the question from general $b$ to $b=4$, and it is sure unusual to see $x$ instead of $n$ or $i$ in the summation.

Comment: I thought that was the problem, that I was being too general. Is there anything wrong with what I did? I don't understand what the point of your comment was @Thus

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with what you did, but because me and @julien gave you general arguments on how you can approach the problem so that it works for any $b$ sure it will work for $b=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think others are taking the wrong view, here - how do you prove that the function is $e^x$. We already have a definition for powers, let's use it.

Let's start by defining

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

Now,

$$
\begin{align}
f(x+y) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}x^iy^{n-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i \sum_{n=i}^{\infty}\frac{y^{n-i}}{n!}\binom{n}{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i \sum_{n=i}^{\infty}\frac{y^{n-i}}{i!(n-i)!}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!}\sum_{n=i}^{\infty}\frac{y^{n-i}}{(n-i)!}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{n!}\\
&=f(x)f(y)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we are looking at a function of the form $f(x)=a^x$ (because it's a power function - addition becomes multiplication, $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$), for some $a$. So what is $a$? For that, we look at f(1).

$$
f(1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = a
$$
Now, $a$ isn't a rational number, and if we pretend we don't know $e$, then it's a number we've never seen before.

And so, we have $f(x)=e^x$, because the constant, $a$, happens to be Euler's number, $e$.

And if you want to look at the specific case of $e^4$, then notice that $f(1)=e$, and $f(2n)=f(n+n)=f(n)f(n)$, so $f(2)=f(1)^2=e^2$, and $f(4)=f(2)^2=e^4$.

Answer (score 3):

If we denote by
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!},$$
then we have $f(0)=1$ and 
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^n}{n!})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=f(x),$$
so $f=\exp$: the unique solution of the differential equation $f'=f, f(0)=1$.

Comment: Nice try but $$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}, $$ you need a lot more analysis here to prove  it

Comment: How did you go from ∑n=1∞xn−1(n−1)!=f(x), to f = exp? Is that just a known definition?

Comment: he just changes the index, he use the definition that the exponential function is the unique function which has the properties $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$. there are a lot more and to answer your question, we really need to know which one you are using

Comment: @DominicMichaelis You proofed again!

Comment: @DominicMichaelis $f$ is a power series with disc of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$ by test ratio so we can differentiate term by term.

Comment: @julien gee I am so stupid, thanks again

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I don't think that the OP knows this, and so you should mention it somewhere.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I do not think  (at least  pedagogically) that we must every time give the details, it might be annoying.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, I don't think the OP would have been given this question to solve if he didn't know that...